# How to save the latest image tag to variable and use that variable to pass into oras pull cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I have a shell script which has below script

```
mkdir -p /tmp
cd /tmp
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | oras login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

 aws ecr describe-images \
--registry-id 123456789 --repository-name test/json-management/artifacts/test-json \
--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[*]' --output text \
| tr '\t' '\n' \
| tail -1

oras pull 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/json-management/artifacts/test-json:1.0-11-7f203685052546633c0b17c99ec7c8d765629df4
```

I am trying to dynamically get the latest image tag save it to variable and replace it with version 1.0-11-7f203685052546633c0b17c99ec7c8d765629df4 above

I couldn't find in aws cli docs how to save it to variable and use that variable to pass in next query

Comment: Does the `aws ecr describe-images` command actually print out the image tag that you want? If so, you just need to capture that output into a variable by wrapping it in `$()`, like `image_tag = $(aws ecr describe-images ...)`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, when I do latesttag = $(aws er describe-images) I am getting the returned value stored as string "aws-tag-version", and this print 
echo 12345789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/artifacts/test-json:$latesttag
12345789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/artifacts/test-json:"12435445" which is wrong and it should be  12345789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/artifacts/test-json:12435445

Comment: Maybe edit your question to show your code where you are actually trying to set the environment variable, so we can point out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score -2):

To save the latest image tag to a variable and use it to pass into the `oras pull` command, you can use a shell script or a programming language that supports executing shell commands. Here's an example using bash shell:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Replace 'your-image-repo' and 'your-image-name' with the actual repository and image name
repository="your-image-repo"
image_name="your-image-name"

# Get the latest tag using the 'oras' command and save it to the 'latest_tag' variable
latest_tag=$(oras search $repository/$image_name | grep -o 'Tags: [^,]*' | awk '{print $2}')

# Check if the 'latest_tag' variable is not empty
if [ -n "$latest_tag" ]; then
    echo "Latest image tag is: $latest_tag"

    # Now you can use the 'latest_tag' variable in the 'oras pull' command
    oras pull $repository/$image_name:$latest_tag
else
    echo "No tags found for the image."
fi
```

Make sure you have `oras` installed and accessible in your environment to use this script. Replace `'your-image-repo'` and `'your-image-name'` with the actual repository and image name you want to pull from.

Save the script to a file (e.g., `pull_latest_image.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x pull_latest_image.sh`), and then run it (`./pull_latest_image.sh`) to pull the latest image with the tag into your local environment.

Comment: aws ecr describe-images --registry-id 123456789 --repository-name test/json-management/artifacts/test-json \
           --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' --output text (this is printing correct version)
latesttag=(aws ecr describe-images --registry-id 986695000930 --repository-name mqd/flip-flop-configuration-management/artifacts/flip-flop-configuration-json \
           --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]')
echo latesttag
echo $latesttag - This is printing 'aws'

Comment: Did you use Chat-GPT to generate this answer?

Comment: Mark B - No, I didn't use the chatGPT, if you pointing it to me